# How to get the ActualWidth and ActualHeight dynamically of a customcontrol?

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a custom control, ccTextBlock placed inside a ScrollViewer. The customcontrol will be changing sizes (vertically) when different strings are sent to it through the binding. The custom control will remain on the display, but will change as text elsewhere on the screen is selected.

How can I obtain the actual width and height of the custom control only *after* and with each text string sent to it?  (Using OnApplyTemplate() did not work as it seems to be called only once on the first construction of the custom control.)

Thanks for any replies.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <wc:ccTextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

***Update***: Perhaps a better way to phrase this question would be "How to get the height of an element when it is inside a ScrollViewer". Here is the definition of ccTextBlock:

```
     public class ccTextBlock : Control
{

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ccTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    static ccTextBlock()
    {
        // Initialize as lookless control
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ccTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ccTextBlock)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        //Effectively apply the template
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" ActualHeight is {0}", this.ActualHeight.ToString()));
        var x = this.FontSize;
    }
}
```

Where Generic.xaml is:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ccTextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ccTextBlock}">
                <!-- Control Layout -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />                  
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I think there is not enough information. What is the purpose of getting ActualWidth? Maybe you could intercept changes to the Text property in you user control?

Comment: @Bjorn I'll update the question. But the problem seems to be that when the TextBlock is inside the ScrollViewer, I can't get back the total height the TextBlock would be. (I hope I said that right).

Comment: Can you get this.ActualHeight in the Text-property's setter?

Comment: @Bjorn Nope. Apparently the ScrollViewer changes things. There is apparently more here then meets the eye, too bad it was downvoted.

Comment: @Bjorn I need to calculate the ascender, descender, and baseline qualities of the printed text. (That's why I need its actual size). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are the properties that contain the current `width` and `height` of the control.

If you are looking for an Event that notifies about changes, it would be the `FrameworkElement.SizeChanged` event. You could register for this event in the `OnApplyTemplate` implementation.